# Twitter API since_id returning every result still

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm trying to utilise the 'since_id' parameter for Twitter's search API and not having much luck...I used it around a year ago on a previous version of my site and it seemed to work well but now, instead of returning all tweets since I retrieved the previous round of tweets, it's not returning anything.

No matter what search term I get JSON data for, I also get a warning:

"warning":"adjusted since_id to 69477074326401025 (), requested since_id was older than allowed -- since_id removed for pagination."

I would have thought if I searched for something that was older than a day or so I'd get this, but some feeds I'm pulling through have a last updated time of 10 seconds..!

Does anyone know why this happens or whether you can pass an extra parameter the first time to make it work?

Trying this on my dev site at the moment but the live version it will be pushed to if I can get it to work is www.twitgeek.net

Thanks dudes

Comment: it is just a warning generated by API internals. if it does not work, then it means you don't have a tweet since `#since_id`.

Comment: Sorry dude if you read above you will see that there clearly are tweets since that time, some of the feeds are getting updated with tweets every second, so it makes no sense :(

Comment: Interestingly it is working for me with given `since_id` above.

Comment: Don't worry, the since_id doesn't work like this exactly, for some reason it was always returned as too old. If max_id is used instead, it gives the exact result I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the 'since_id' part of the object was always returned as "too old" and re-generated, no matter what search I made, no matter how often the feed was updated.

'max_id' is the one that works properly for this purpose. My new code made a call using since_id but passing in the max_id as the parameter to the URL like this:

```
//search.twitter.com/search.json?&q=test&since_id=' + previousObject.max_id_str
```

Using this instead seems to work like a charm!